# Show that $P_n(x) ={}_2F_1\left(-n,n+1;1;\frac{1-x}{2}\right)$.

Tags: calculus, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I am told that
$$P_n(x) ={}_2F_1\left(-n,n+1;1;\tfrac{1-x}{2}\right),$$
where $P_n(x)$ is Legendre polynomial and ${}_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)$ is hypergeometric function. I am just wondering how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand $P_n(x)$ in powers of $1-x$ starting with Rodrigues's formula and compare the result with the hypergeometric series.

Comment: In Rodriguez's formula, we take n to be non-negative integer,hence expansion in powers of $1-x$ gives you finite sum using Binomial theorem,where as in hypergeometric series I need infinite sum,how can I compare the two?

Comment: Can you explain me a more.....may be I misunderstood your hint.

Comment: Since $a=-n$, the hypergeometric series will terminate.

Comment: Okay got it,thanks a lot!